# How to set vertical and horizontal border in flutter datatable?

Tags: flutter, dart, datatable

As I am new to flutter, I could not set the `border` in `DataTable`. Can anybody tell me how can I do that by using `DataTable` Widget? As per my requirement, I have to give borders between each rows and columns. Only I found the `showBottomBorder` properties in that but not satisfied! because I have to do a table like structure with black borders in each rows and columns. Please help me how can I achieve this!

Thanks in advance :)

[This is the image link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l7TgU.png)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l7TgU.png)

Below is my code.

```
Widget bodyData(PatientDataNotifier patientDataNotifier) {
    return SingleChildScrollView(
      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
      child: DataTable(
              onSelectAll: (b) {},
              sortColumnIndex: 1,
              sortAscending: true,
              columns: <DataColumn>[
                DataColumn(
                  label: Text('Profile'),
                  numeric: false,
                ),
                DataColumn(
                    label: Text('Name'),
                    numeric: false,
                    onSort: (i, b) {
                    //  patientDataNotifier.sortPatient();
                      print('$i $b');
                     },
                    tooltip: 'First Name'),
                DataColumn(
                  label: Text('Age'),
                  numeric: false,
                ),
                DataColumn(
                  label: Text('Assigned Slots'),
                  numeric: false,
                ),
                DataColumn(
                  label: Text('Completed Slots'),
                  numeric: false,
                )
              ],
              rows: patientDataNotifier.patientMaster.map(
                    (detail) => DataRow(
                      cells: [
                        DataCell(CircleAvatar(radius: 25, backgroundImage: NetworkImage(detail.profile_pic),)),
                        DataCell(Text(detail.name), showEditIcon: false),
                        DataCell(Text(detail.age.toString()), showEditIcon: false),
                        DataCell(Text(detail.assigned_slots), showEditIcon: false),
                        DataCell(Text(detail.completed_slots), showEditIcon: false)
                      ],
                    ),
                  ).toList(),
        ),
      );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: PreferredSize(
        preferredSize: const Size.fromHeight(80),
        child: Consumer<PatientDataNotifier>(
          builder: (context, patientDataNotifier, _){
            return appBarSection('Patient Details', patientDataNotifier);
          },
        ),
      ),
      //appBar: appBarSection('Patient Details'),
      body: Container(
        child: Consumer<PatientDataNotifier>(
          builder: (context, patientDataNotifier, _){
            return bodyData(patientDataNotifier);
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget appBarSection(String title, PatientDataNotifier patientDataNotifier) {
    return AppBar(
      title: Text(title),
      actions: [
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: SizedBox(
            width: 150,
            child: TextFormField(
              controller: nameController,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                hintText: "Search",
                hintStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 16, color: Colors.white),
                isDense: true,
                suffixIcon: Icon(Icons.search, color: Colors.white),
                focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16),
                  borderSide: BorderSide(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    width: 2.0,
                  ),
                ),
                enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16),
                  borderSide: BorderSide(style: BorderStyle.none),
                ),
                filled: true,
                fillColor: Colors.lightBlue.shade200,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

You can actually use DataTable's `border` property to achieve this;

```dart
DataTable(
  ...
  border: TableBorder(
    horizontalInside: BorderSide(color: Colors.white, width: 0.7),
    verticalInside: BorderSide(color: Colors.white, width: 0.7),
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
    bottom: BorderSide(color: Colors.white, width: 0.7),
    top: BorderSide(color: Colors.white, width: 0.7),
    left: BorderSide(color: Colors.white, width: 0.7),
    right: BorderSide(color: Colors.white, width: 0.7),
  ),
  ...
);
```

Answer (score 2):

Using DataTable `decoration` can be used to have table border. to have inner-border line, we can put `VerticalDivider()` widget inside `columns` and every `DataRow's cells`.

[image: output]

As you can see I'm just missing centering Text.

```dart
  Widget buildTable(BuildContext context) {
    return Theme(
          data: Theme.of(context).copyWith(dividerColor: Colors.black),
          child: DataTable(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                border: Border.all(
              width: 1,
              color: Colors.black,
            )),
            columns: const <DataColumn>[
              DataColumn(label: Text("Sport", textAlign: TextAlign.center)),
              DataColumn(label: VerticalDivider()),
              DataColumn(
                  label: Text("Total Players", textAlign: TextAlign.center))
            ],
            rows: const <DataRow>[
              DataRow(
                cells: <DataCell>[
                  DataCell(Text('Soccer')),
                  DataCell(VerticalDivider()),
                  DataCell(Text("11")),
                ],
              ),
              DataRow(
                cells: <DataCell>[
                  DataCell(Text('Hockey')),
                  DataCell(VerticalDivider()),
                  DataCell(Text("11")),
                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `dividerThickness` to determine the Thickness of you divider, unfortunately there is no ability to add vertical divider in DataTable.

Answer (score 0):

I used `Container` with "`decoration: BoxDecoration(border: Border.all(color: Colors.grey[300]!))`" in `DataCell`.
Also I gave constraints "`height: 50.0, width: 100.0`" for my Container, because my Content is dynamic.
And finally, I make columnSpacing: 0 into DataTable options.